# Is it sane to use the Jquery Asynchronous Image Loader (JAIL) for every image and have the data-src attribute be the trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've recently been working on some legacy web app code that uses JAIL (https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL). Is it safe/sane to use JAIL on every "img" tag rather than having an additional class/id to limit the scope of JAIL to specific images?

For instance, is it advisable to do this (what our current code does):

```
$('img').jail();
```

And then expect JAIL to only kick in on images that actually have a "data-src" attribute? (90% of our images do not have data-src, and our expectation is that only data-src images will be handled by JAIL. Which seems to work most of the time, but there are a few errors that may be related to this after upgrading JAIL to 1.0.0, and it also seems like the overhead is a little crazy -- JAIL has to inspect every image?).

Should we instead using something like the img.lazy approach that the docs and examples seem to advocate (I say *seem* because they show this, but don't specifically recommend against the other)?

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
     $('img.lazy').jail();
   });
 </script>
```

I'm not yet sure if the errors I'm seeing after upgrading are related to JAIL itself or other stuff on our site (there is a lot going on, much of it dynamic, and I'm not a JavaScript guru, so it's non-trivial to debug at the moment). (I'm seeing errors like those that were reported on earlier versions of JAIL, hence trying to upgrade from 0.9.5 to 1.0.0: https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL/issues/22 .)

Also, I'm concerned that even if our issues are not related to our current JAIL setup (something else), it may still be slow/expensive because we're asking JAIL to inspect every image?

Any (reasonable ;)) advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin acts on the data-src attribute, target that.

```
$("img[data-src]").jail();
```

Comment: Ohhhhh, check out the big brain on Kevin ;). Seriously, thanks, I should have thought of that myself, will try it ASAP.

Comment: Works well, thanks again. (I still have some other JAIL related issues, I think, but this at least saves all the overhead of inspecting every image, without other code changes.)